# Why does my boot screen list several kernel versions?

Tags: kernel, boot, upgrade

After I upgrade my kernel, the next time I start my machine several versions of the kernel will be listed on the boot screen, and I can use up and down arrow keys to choose what kernel I want to launch.

Does that mean:

- the old kernel versions haven't been overwritten by the new one?
- each version of the kernel will take some hard drive space, and each time the kernel is upgraded, more and more space will be taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, but the size of the kernels are extremely small. Here are the total sizes for all the kernels on one of my machines:

```
# ls -l /boot/
total 66307
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    1024 Feb 18 18:18 grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      40 Feb 18 18:18 initramfs -> initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.15.3-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4722276 Jan  7 02:16 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.14.12-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4725024 Jan  6 14:59 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.14.12-gentoo.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4553984 Jan 11 03:09 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.14.13-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4555532 Jan 22 03:09 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.14.14-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4544696 Jan 18 01:49 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.14.14-gentoo.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4577944 Feb  4 03:56 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.15.1-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4750536 Feb  8 15:42 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.15.2-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4745248 Feb 18 18:18 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.15.3-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4745760 Feb 13 23:06 initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.15.3-gentoo.old
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      44 Feb 18 18:18 initramfs.old -> initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.15.3-gentoo.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3645904 Jan  7 02:15 kernel-4.14.12-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3645904 Jan 11 03:08 kernel-4.14.13-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3641808 Jan 22 03:09 kernel-4.14.14-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3682768 Feb  4 03:55 kernel-4.15.1-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3682768 Feb  8 15:42 kernel-4.15.2-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3682768 Feb 13 23:05 kernel-4.15.3-gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3682768 Feb 18 18:18 kernel-4.15.4-gentoo
drwx------ 2 root root   12288 Apr  4  2017 lost+found
# du -hd1 /boot
12K     /boot/lost+found
2.0M    /boot/grub
67M     /boot
# du -hd1 /lib/modules
4.1M    /lib/modules/4.14.14-gentoo
4.2M    /lib/modules/4.14.13-gentoo
4.2M    /lib/modules/4.14.12-gentoo
4.1M    /lib/modules/4.15.3-gentoo
4.1M    /lib/modules/4.15.1-gentoo
4.1M    /lib/modules/4.15.2-gentoo
4.1M    /lib/modules/4.15.4-gentoo
29M     /lib/modules/
```

So for seven kernels, it takes 100MB. That's hardly anything, and it gives me the ability to revert to a previous version of the kernel if I have a problem booting into the most recent one. I occasionally clear out old kernels (about every 3-4 months) but it doesn't affect the running of the system.

**TL;DR**: Don't worry about previous kernels too much. They take almost no space, and provide insurance against an unbootable system.

Comment: also, it's easy to remove old kernel versions if you don't want them any more.  exactly how varies according to distribution.  e.g. on Debian, you could run `apt-get purge linux-image-4.12.0-2-amd64 linux-headers-4.12.0-2-amd64 linux-headers-4.12.0-2-common` to remove the binary kernel image and the (optional) related kernel header files for linux kernel 4.12.   On RH or Centos or Fedora, you'd use `yum` or `rpm` to remove the relevant kernel packages.

Comment: @cas I'd always keep at least one previous kernel on updates though, just in case something in the new kernel panics the system!

Comment: Yes, definitely.  But when you've got half a dozen or more old kernels that you haven't booted for ages, it's probably time to clean up some of the older ones.  I usually keep at least the last 3 kernel versions, sometimes more.  Like you said, they don't take much space and they may end up being very useful.

Comment: @cas As I use a source-based distribution, I remove the previous kernel sources right away (keeping the `.config` files) though. The sources do take a fair amount of space (1.3GB for 4.15.4 alone!)

Comment: if that's in response to my example of purging the linux-headers-* packages, they aren't the full sources, just the headers - required to compile/link stuff like 3rd-party kernel modules (e.g. free software like zfs.ko or proprietary software like nvidia.ko).   still large, but nowhere near as large as the full source.

Comment: @cas No, it's just my specific case. Most people use binary distros and generally don't experience the fun of compiling their own kernels every release :-)